# Apollo GraphQL tutorial: "GraphQLError: Cannot query field \"id\" on type \"LaunchConnection\"."

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm trying to follow the Apollo GraphQL tutorial at this step, https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers/#run-queries-in-the-playground. Following https://github.com/apollographql/fullstack-tutorial, I ran

```
cd final/server && npm i && npm start
```

as well as

```
cd final/client && npm i && npm start
```

(For the `final/server`, I first deleted the `package-lock.json` before running `npm install` because I was running into issues with the `sqlite3` dependency).

However, in the GraphQL playground on `localhost:4000`, if I try to run the query

```
query GetLaunches {
  launches {
    id
    mission {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error response

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Cannot query field \"id\" on type \"LaunchConnection\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 3,
            "column": 5
          }
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "GraphQLError: Cannot query field \"id\" on type \"LaunchConnection\".",
              "    at Object.Field (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectType.js:64:31)",
              "    at Object.enter (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:334:29)",
              "    at Object.enter (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:385:25)",
              "    at visit (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:252:26)",
              "    at Object.validate (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:63:22)",
              "    at validate (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:211:32)",
              "    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:124:42)",
              "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
              "    at fulfilled (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:4:58)",
              "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "message": "Cannot query field \"mission\" on type \"LaunchConnection\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 4,
            "column": 5
          }
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "GraphQLError: Cannot query field \"mission\" on type \"LaunchConnection\".",
              "    at Object.Field (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectType.js:64:31)",
              "    at Object.enter (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:334:29)",
              "    at Object.enter (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:385:25)",
              "    at visit (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:252:26)",
              "    at Object.validate (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:63:22)",
              "    at validate (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:211:32)",
              "    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:124:42)",
              "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
              "    at fulfilled (/Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/final/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:4:58)",
              "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

(See screenshot below).

[image]

Any idea what is causing this? I do see a GraphQL schema in the right pop-up window which appears to contain these fields:

```
directive @cacheControl(
  maxAge: Int
  scope: CacheControlScope
) on FIELD_DEFINITION | OBJECT | INTERFACE
enum CacheControlScope {
  PUBLIC
  PRIVATE
}

type Launch {
  id: ID!
  site: String
  mission: Mission
  rocket: Rocket
  isBooked: Boolean!
}

type LaunchConnection {
  cursor: String!
  hasMore: Boolean!
  launches: [Launch]!
}

type Mission {
  name: String
  missionPatch(size: PatchSize): String
}

type Mutation {
  bookTrips(launchIds: [ID]!): TripUpdateResponse!
  cancelTrip(launchId: ID!): TripUpdateResponse!
  login(email: String): String
}

enum PatchSize {
  SMALL
  LARGE
}

type Query {
  launches(
    pageSize: Int
    after: String
  ): LaunchConnection!
  launch(id: ID!): Launch
  me: User
}

type Rocket {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  type: String
}

type TripUpdateResponse {
  success: Boolean!
  message: String
  launches: [Launch]
}

scalar Upload

type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  trips: [Launch]!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the schema you provided, Query `launches` returns type `LaunchConnection`

```
type LaunchConnection {
  cursor: String!
  hasMore: Boolean!
  launches: [Launch]!
}

type Query {
  launches: LaunchConnection!
}
```

Your query, below, is expected to return type `LaunchConnection`

```
query GetLaunches {
  launches {
    id
    mission {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

But `LaunchConnection` has fields `cursor`, `hasMore` & `launches`. You are asking for fields `id` & `mission` on the incorrect type. You should first dive into the `launches` field on `LaunchConnection` then you can ask for fields on the `Launch` type. Your query should look like the following:

```
query GetLaunches {
    launches {
        launches {
            id
            mission {
                name
            }
        }
    }
}
```